[SOLVED]Enhanced Einstein Bot not invoking my Omni-Channel flow
I am working with an Enhanced Einstein Bot in Salesforce, and for some reason, the bot is not invoking my Omni-Channel flow.
bot:

Omni-Channel Flow: Currently simple, set up only to create an entry in a custom log object  as a test.


The bot interacts correctly with users, but when it is supposed to invoke the Omni-Channel flow, nothing happens.
No logs are being created in the custom object, indicating that the flow is not being called


It worked! I did this: Basically, I recreated the bot, leaving the inbound and outbound checkboxes to be automatically created.
